# FOSUserBundle to check if user is not activated

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Is there a way when using the usermanager and FOSUserBundle to figure out if there is a user created but not yet activated yet? Meaning the user isEnabled flag is set at 0?

Answer (score 0):

You can use userManager's `findUserBy` method which returns one user for the given criteria if such a user exists.

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
public function findUserBy(array $criteria)
{
    return $this->repository->findOneBy($criteria);
}
```

i.e.

```
$this->userManager->findUserBy(array('enabled' => 0));
```